# iMac Spring Tool Suite start warning

Tags: macos, spring-tool-suite

If I will start STS after download I get the following Warning:

> The JVM shared library "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
>    does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Afterwards the start procedure will not preceed.

If I enter **java -version** at terminal the right Java Version is installed (JDK 8_xx).

Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the STS/Eclipse launcher tries to use the wrong JVM install. You can specify the JVM to use yourself in the STS.ini file, take a look at:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

Hope this helps!!!